# Scroll Down AnnotateViewer

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, mkannotationview

Can you help me with this in VB.Net
Im trying to have a shortcut here for my AnnotateViewer
when i press "Ctrl + Down"
the view must scroll down.

Here's the code that i tried

```
Dim pt As Point = iView.ScrollPosition
    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad0 Then
      pt.Y -= 99999
      Msg("Scroll Down")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah now it works.
I used these codes

```
 If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad2 Then
        iView.ScrollPosition += New Point(0, -90)
    ElseIf e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad8 Then
        iView.ScrollPosition += New Point(0, 90)
    ElseIf e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad4 Then
        iView.ScrollPosition += New Point(50, 0)
    ElseIf e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad6 Then
        iView.ScrollPosition += New Point(-50, 0)

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

iView.ScrollPosition = new Point(x,y)

Change the value of x for horizontal scroll, and y for vertical scroll bar.